# How to while just last x lines - Bash

Tags: bash, shell, do-while

I have a bash script and log file.

```
while read -r date time ...
do
...
...
done < logfile
```

It's working all lines. But log file is too big and sometimes I need to run this script for last few lines. How can I do like this?

```
./script.sh -last 30
```

Mean while just last 30 lines.

or just:

```
./script.sh 30
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put a `tail -n 30` in front of it:

```
tail -n 30 logfile | while read -r date time ...
do
...
...
done
```

Comment: a tiny correction: logfile must be streamed into tail then

Comment: Yes indeed, I forgot to add logfile in `tail` command, thanks!

Comment: If the body of the while loop needs to run in the current shell, switch to process substitution: `while read -r date time; do ... done < <(tail -n 30 logfile)`.